# Drawing on top of an uploaded image file

Tags: java, swing

I have a paint application and I draw on a JPanel. I want to be able to upload an image file in the JPanel area and then draw it. I can upload the file but cannot draw over it, because the image file is above the JPanel. I cannot draw anything on it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `paintComponent` method of the `JPanel` instance. Therein, you will draw everything directly to it's `Graphics` object; first draw the image and then draw whatever else you want over it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a UI guy, but I believe you can use a Canvas (JCanvas?) to hold both the picture and allow you to draw on it.

Comment: when i first draw the image file of the size equal to the jcanvas/jpanel then every graphics element i draw on the jcanvas/jpanel goes below the canvas/panel and it not visible....using jvanvas didnt help